# Link bash script with PHP, WordPress and Node sass

Tags: php, node.js, bash, shell, sass

Just need to understand I have the logic in order. I have a server, with Wordpress installed. I have sass installed.

I would like to be able to link a plugin checkbox from WordPress that runs

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

and stops the

```
--watch
```

Would the best way be create a `sass_run.sh` file with the code, and run that through a PHP function that runs the command directly on the server?

Is this the correct way to approach it? I am not sure about permissions I just wanted to see I was heading the right direction.

Comment: why don't you run this command from PHP script?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it whilst php_safemode is on... should I use exec() or shell_exec()

Comment: If you don't know how to run the command `sass --watch input.scss:output.css` from PHP, how were you planning on running the shell script from PHP?

Comment: I was going to use `$output = shell_exec('sass --watch input.scss:output.css');` I just wasnt sure which approach to take and if I am over complicating it..

Comment: then wrap within an if statement and a controller in wordpress admin menu...

Comment: This sounds like a huge hack. I don't know what you're trying to do, but I don't think you should do it this way. Sass is a build tool, PHP and WordPress are web technologies. Don't mix in Sass in server-side technologies unless you have to ( like if you're building another CodePen or Sass-meister ).

Comment: I just want to compile the sass and enable watch, so this is why I wasn't sure how I can incorporate the two.. I am not fussed but the web server is where I need the files..and so makes sense.. but I guess I am going to have to seperate them..

Comment: @Norris I think I may just link the php `if` statement with `sass --update` but yes, I guess it is like codepen

Comment: You're not explaining what it is exactly you're trying to achieve. If you want to use PHP to compile Sass, you might just use http://leafo.net/scssphp/ or run `exec('sass input.scss:output.css);'` without the watch. I don't see the reason for trying to handle asynchronous code ( sass --watch ) with PHP.

If you want to recompile every now and then, use AJAX, make JavaScript request the compiled result from your server-side script every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: Thanks for all of your inputs I believe I have what I need now to implement something more rigid, and thanks @Norris I am greatful for your help.